# How to run a script in Next js

Tags: typescript, next.js

I have to use an external library, but it doesn't work

Below is the custom hook

```
const useDaumPostTest = () => {
  const Test = (asdsa: string) => {
    console.log(asdsa)
    const Element = (
      <>
        <Script defer src="//t1.daumcdn.net/mapjsapi/bundle/postcode/prod/postcode.v2.js" strategy="beforeInteractive" />
        <Script>
          {`
      new daum.Postcode({
      oncomplete: function(data) {
         }
      }).open();
  `}
        </Script>
      </>
    )
    return Element
  }
  return {Test}
}

export default useDaumPostTest
```

And  it is used

```
const {Test} = useDaumPostTest()
  const handleClicks = () => {
    Test('why not')
    // open({onComplete: handleComplete})
  }
```

it is working  code

```
<div>
{test}
</div>
```

but

```
const handleClicks = () => {
    Test('why not')
    // open({onComplete: handleComplete})
  }
```

it is not working

how can i use customHook in use onClick?

Comment: How/where/when are you calling `handleClicks`?

Comment: it's mean button click